# AS3 Get currentFrame of current MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, frame, movieclip

How can I get the frame number of the current MovieClip. I am trying `this.currentFrame` but it's coming up as undefined.

To clarify, I'm **not** looking to find out currentFrame of root or a child MC; instead I am looking to find the currentFrame of the current MovieClip.

Comment: what is a current MovieClip in your case?

Comment: Well I have a checkBox MC. Inside there I have an invisible button, which when clicked, I want to go to the next frame or go to the original. There are two states on the checkBox MC, frame1: checked and frame2 unchecked. I want to do. I've tried: `if(this.currentFrame == 1){ gotoAndStop(2); } else { gotoAndStop(1); }`

Comment: if you send me fla i will check it, because i dont get it, for example where is that if statement? inside of a checkBoxMc or root?

Comment: also you dont need a invisible button, you can get the state of checkbox with (checkBox.selected) it returns boolean of a state of checkbox

Comment: In fact, `this.currentFrame` is the proper qualifier for the task you describe. Check if that `this` you're querying is a `MovieClip` descendant and not say `TextField` or `SimpleButton`.

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil, the conditional is inside the MC.

Comment: Please post your code. It's really tedious to ask for every detail to answer your question. Post all the code in your MC. I bet on a misused closure, btw.